# Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator

Tags: azure-storage

Azure storage is on a local sql server. I have run DSInit /sqlinstance:. which completes without errors but when I try to run my app I still get Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator.

Is there some other setting I have missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have SQL Express installed:

1. Click Start, point to All Programs, and then click Windows Azure SDK
   v1.4
2. Right-click Windows Azure SDK Command Prompt, then click Run as
   Administrator
3. In the Windows Azure SDK Command Prompt window, type the following
   command: `DSInit /sqlInstance:<SQLServerInstance>;`

http://blog.nimbo.com/error-failed-to-initialize-windows-azure-storage-emulator/

If not, please post a full log of the error.

Comment: Thank you wcdolphin but as I said in my initial post I have already run DSInit /sqlinstance:. DSInit runs without error. VS10 returns Windows Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator. Unable to start Development Storage. Failed to start Storage Emulator: the SQL Server instance ‘localhost\SQLExpress’ could not be found.   Please configure the SQL Server instance for Storage Emulator using the ‘DSInit’ utility in the Windows Azure SDK.

Comment: oopsy daisy ... forgot to mention wcdolphin that I don't have SQL Express installed. Do I have to download and install SQL Express just to tell it I don't want to use SQL Express? Also I am using Azure SDK 1.6 not 1.4. Does that make a difference?

Comment: you need to have sql server installed for azure storage emulator to start. emulator uses that internally.